# Remove extra bullet above the payment method in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, checkout

My problem is that there is a bullet above the checked pay method "Betaling via overschrijving", on my woocommerce checkout page, and I have no idea how to get rid of this extra bullet:

[image: Picture Checkout bullet]

[Here is my checkout webpage](https://www.worldline-paper.be/afrekenen/). You may have to place something into the cart for it to work.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the question? As a best practice, please provide steps within your question for others to easily understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add in your active child theme (or active theme) `styles.css` file the following rule:

```css
.wpb_text_column ul.payment_methods li {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
```

It will remove the undesired small bullet from payment methods...